# Use lapply on condition in R

Tags: r, conditional-statements, lapply

it's easier to explain what I want to do if you look at the code first but essentially I think I want to use lapply on a condition but I wasn't able to do it.

```
library("tidyverse")
names <- rep(c("City A", "City B"), each = 11)
year <- rep(c(2010:2020), times = 2)
col_1 <- c(1, 17, 34, 788, 3, 4, 78, 98, 650, 45, 20,
           23, 45, 56, 877, 54, 12, 109, 167, 12, 19, 908)
col_2 <- c(3, 4, 23, 433, 2, 45, 34, 123, 98, 76, 342,
           760, 123, 145, 892, 23, 5, 90, 40, 12, 67, 98)

df <- as.data.frame(cbind(names, year, col_1, col_2))

df <- df %>%
  mutate(col_1 = as.numeric(col_1),
         col_2 = as.numeric(col_2))
```

I want every numeric column in the year 2018 and later to be rounded with round_any to a value which is a multiple of three (plyr::round_any, 3)
What I tried is this:

```
df_2018 <- df %>%
  filter(year >= 2018)

df <- df %>%
  filter(!(year >= 2018))
  
df_2018[, c(3:4)] <- lapply(df_2018[, c(3:4)], plyr::round_any, 3)
  
df <- rbind(df, df_2018)
```

In reality, there's about 50 numeric columns and tons of rows. What I tried works in theory but I would like to achieve it with less code and cleaner.
I am new to using lapply and I failed trying to combine it with an ifelse because I don't want it to change my year column.

Thank you for everyone who takes the time out of their day to look at this :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `dplyr::across` and `if_else` you could do:

```r
library(dplyr)

df |> 
  mutate(across(-c(names, year), ~ if_else(year >= 2018, plyr::round_any(.x, 3), .x)))
#>     names year col_1 col_2
#> 1  City A 2010     1     3
#> 2  City A 2011    17     4
#> 3  City A 2012    34    23
#> 4  City A 2013   788   433
#> 5  City A 2014     3     2
#> 6  City A 2015     4    45
#> 7  City A 2016    78    34
#> 8  City A 2017    98   123
#> 9  City A 2018   651    99
#> 10 City A 2019    45    75
#> 11 City A 2020    21   342
#> 12 City B 2010    23   760
#> 13 City B 2011    45   123
#> 14 City B 2012    56   145
#> 15 City B 2013   877   892
#> 16 City B 2014    54    23
#> 17 City B 2015    12     5
#> 18 City B 2016   109    90
#> 19 City B 2017   167    40
#> 20 City B 2018    12    12
#> 21 City B 2019    18    66
#> 22 City B 2020   909    99
```

Comment: This solution assumes that OP knows that 'names' and 'year' are the only non numeric columns. by slightly changing the line to `df %>%
  mutate(across(where(is.numeric), ~ if_else(year >= 2018, plyr::round_any(.x, 3), .x)))`  one could get a more beneficial form if one does not want to hardcode the non numeric columns.

Comment: @Sandwichnick. Yep. You are right. But using `where(is.numeric)` (which was my first thought too) will also apply to the numeric `year`.

Comment: Thank you, that works perfectly! And yes, I thought about where(is.numeric) too but the year would change. Thank you for your solution :)

Comment: Actually it's very weird. It did work for me the first time but now the values for col_1 and col_2 aren't changing at all. It also doesn't work for my real data. I don't get any errors. Does anyone have any ideas why this is happening? I even restarted R.

Answer (score 0):

Using `data.table`:

```
cols <- grep("^col_[0-9]+$", names(df), value = TRUE)
setDT(df)[year >= 2018, (cols) := round(.SD / 3) * 3, .SDcols = cols]
```

Comment: I should have specified that the columns in the actual dataframe do have very different names. There's no way to use regex or something for them. Thank you for the alternative answer though